# String manipulation SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a row of strings that are in the following format:

'Order was assigned to lastname,firsname'

I need to cut this string down into just the last and first name but it is always a different name for each record.

The 'Order was assigned to' part is always the same.......

Thanks

I am using SQL Server. It is multiple records with different names in each record.

Comment: What RDBMS? This is something that will vary a lot depending on the answer.

Comment: I assume you want to do this within the query/using SQL?

Comment: When you say, "a row of string", do you mean multiple columns each with one of these strings, or do you actually mean multiple rows, each with one column of these strings? The terminology for SQL is roughly equivalent to: row = record, column = field.

Comment: "The 'Order was assigned to' part is always the same......."

What's the point of having this stored in the database in the first place if it's always the same?

Comment: @Aircule Nail on the head. In my eagerness to rush out a substring function I didn't consider that!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in T-SQL? Why not strip out what you want in the calling code before you send the query to SQL Server?

Comment: Really the entry in this table should be an Employee ID if that is available... What if someone changes their name after getting married?
With an ID you just go get the current information and that person can get married as much as they want to - You will still know who is in trouble for screwing up the order :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the SUBSTRING methods, you could also use a REPLACE function. I don't know which would have better performance over millions of rows, although I suspect that it would be the SUBSTRING - especially if you were working with CHAR instead of VARCHAR.

```
SELECT REPLACE(my_column, 'Order was assigned to ', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case you can use something like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(str, 23) FROM table
```

However, this is not very scalable, should the format of your strings ever change.

If you are using an Oracle database, you would want to use `SUBSTR` instead.

**Edit:**

For databases where the third parameter is not optional, you could use `SUBSTRING(str, 23, LEN(str))`

Somebody would have to test to see if this is better or worse than subtraction, [as in Martin Smith's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158516/string-manipulation-sql/3158571#3158571) but gives you the same result in the end.

Comment: Done you need 3 arguments in a Substring?

Comment: AFAIK, the third argument (length) is optional. With only two arguments it will go from start position to the end.

Like everything else in the SQL world, this might depend on the particular implementation, though.

Comment: Nope. In SQL Server `Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 The substring function requires 3 argument(s).`

Comment: For SQL Server (at least 2008) this is not the case. The third parameter is required.

Comment: 3rd is optional. - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: @Robert No it isn't. I've tried it in SQL Server and it gives the following `Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 The substring function requires 3 argument(s).` Edit: They aren't using MySQL!

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server

```
   WITH testData AS
    (
    SELECT 'Order was assigned to lastname,firsname' as Col1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Order was assigned to Bloggs, Jo' as Col1
    )

    SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1,23,LEN(Col1)-22) AS Name
    from testData
```

Returns

```
Name

---------------------------------------
lastname,firsname
Bloggs, Jo
```

Answer (score 0):

I would require that a colon or some other delimiter be between the message and the name.
Then you could just search for the index of that character and know that anything after it was the data you need...

Example with format changing over time:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (OrderInfo NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Order was assigned to :Smith,Mary')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('Order was assigned to :Holmes,Larry')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('New Format over time :LootAt,Me')


SELECT      SUBSTRING(OrderInfo, CHARINDEX(':',OrderInfo)+1, LEN(OrderInfo))
FROM        #Temp


DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: So that they can change whatever the message at the front is to whatever in the future.  The rule being that the data is after the delimiter...

Answer (score 0):

on MS SQL Server:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'Order was assigned to lastname,firsname'
declare @strLen1 int = DATALENGTH('Order was assigned to ')
declare @strLen2 int = len(@str)
select @strlen1, @strLen2, substring(@str,@strLen1,@strLen2), 
                  RIGHT(@str, @strlen2-@strlen1)
```